# java- apache http client v4.x- how to extract different elements of response from HTTPResponse object

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

I am working with the Apache HTTP Client and trying to extract content from the response...

I have the response in a HTTP Response object named 'response'.

Now, how do I extract the following from the HTTPResponse object??--

(1) Response content as byte[]
(2) Content length
(3) Mime type
(4) Charset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
instream.read();
```

That's the main codes.
You can see the examples in:httpcomponents-client-4.1.3\examples\org\apache\http\examples\client

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `HttpEntity` and do `getContentLenght()` and `getContentType();`. Here is apache [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html)